# Get elements from dict using multiple keys

Tags: python

If I have:

```
d = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four':4}
```

How can I get values of 'one' and 'three' in one command. Something like this:

```
out = d['one', 'three'] # But it gives an error
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> d = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four':4}
>>> [d[key] for key in 'one', 'three']
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just directly access them:

```
>>> d = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four':4}
>>> [d['one'], d['three']]
[1, 3]
>>>
```

In the method you use, it is searching for the key `('one', 'three')` in `d`, which obviously doesn't exist.